# Monotouch set UIButton highlighted in event handler method

Tags: xamarin.ios, uibutton

I created a button, which I would like to have highlighted when clicked. This is my event handler when the button is clicked.

```
void buttonClicked (object sender, EventArgs e){
        UIButton button = (UIButton)sender;
        button.Highlighted = true;
                    Console.WriteLine(button.Title(UIControlState.Normal));
}
```

The event handler is getting called, because the console is printing out the correct title. However, the button is not being highlighted. What's wrong here?

Comment: Did you create your button in IB or code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use-case suggests the use of the `Selected` property and the `SetImage(highlightBackgroundImg, UIControlState.Selected)`.

```
button.SetImage(img, UIControlState.Selected);
button.TouchUpInside += (s, e) => {
   button.Selected = true;
}
```